# Multiple inheritance in "broken" diamonds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was exploring how multiple inheritance might work in cases where one of the (two) parent classes doesn't inherit from the common base class. Here's the program:

```
'''Demomstration of MRO on 'broken' diamonds'''

class Base:
    def hello(self):
        print('Base')

class Left(Base):
    def hello(self):
        print('Left')
        super().hello()

class Right:
    def hello(self):
        print('Right')
        super().hello()

class Child1(Left, Right):
    '''Class has right edge missing'''
    def hello(self):
        print('Child1')
        super().hello()

class Child2(Right, Left):
    '''Class has left edge missing'''
    def hello(self):
        print('Child2')
        super().hello()

print(help(Child1))
print(help(Child2))

print('Child1 output:')
print('==============')
Child1().hello()
print('\nChild2 output:')
print('==============')
Child2().hello()
```

The `help()` says that in the first case, the MRO will be:

```
 |      Child1
 |      Left
 |      Base
 |      Right
 |      builtins.object
```

While in the second case it will be (please be a little careful: `Right` is actually on the left-hand side here):

```
 |      Child2
 |      Right
 |      Left
 |      Base
 |      builtins.object
```

But the output of the `hello()` functions is:

```
Child1 output:
==============
Child1
Left
Base

Child2 output:
==============
Child2
Right
Left
Base
```

So in the first case, the `Right` class has been entirely skipped! It's almost like the interpreter couldn't reach out to it because there was no connection to follow.

I can understand that this can be explained by working through the C3 Linearization algorithm, but isn't it a bit strange that one class in the hierarchy gets left out while in the mirror-image case it doesn't?

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? In python3 there are no "broken diamonds". You *always* have `object` on top, so in the end there's always a diamond. However if you are using python2 then you are using the deprecated old-style classes, which, AFAIK, do **not** use C3 linearization.

Comment: You can see the problem in the MRO from the `help`: `Base` comes before `Right` for `Child1`, but *doesn't* call `super().hello()`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm afraid I don't understand. :P Why is the order given in the MRO then if it's not followed? Why wasn't that call made?

Comment: @Bakuriu It's Python 3, of course. See the `print()` statements. :)

Comment: @dotslash ... so? `print("Hello")` is valid python2 and prints the exact same thing as in python3. The thing that should have made me realize it was python3 were the calls to `super` inside what would have been old style classes, moreover `super` without arguments.

Comment: @dotslash that order *is* followed, until it gets to `Base.hello`, which **doesn't call `super`**. So it stops there. *"almost like the interpreter couldn't reach out to it because there was no connection to follow"* - no, because the code doesn't tell it to follow the connection!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Excellent! I learned something new today. :-)

Comment: @Bakuriu Surprised! I thought `print()` was pure Python3. Anyway, thanks for participating in this discussion.

Comment: In python2 the `()` are not part of a function call, they are simply grouping parenthesis that do nothing. Same thing as writing `x = (5)` which is the same as `x = 5`. This change for `print(1,2)`. In python3 this produces `1 2` because it's a function call with two arguments, in python2 it produces `(1, 2)` because it just prints the tuple.  However in your code you always use a single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Base.hello` function is "broken" with respect to this test. Consider the `hello` functions in your MRO:

```
Child1.hello
    print('Child1')  # PRINTED
    super().hello()  # super() -> Left
Left.hello
    print('Left')    # PRINTED
    super().hello()  # super() -> BASE
Base.hello
    print('Base')  # PRINTED
    # no call to super()!!!
Right.hello    # NEVER CALLED
    print('Left')
    super().hello()  # super() -> object
builtins.object.hello
```

So basically, once `super().hello` is resolved to `Base.hello`, the `super` chain stops. `Base.hello` misses a call to `super` to advance onto `Right`. Thus, `Right.hello` isn't called, even though `Right` is in the MRO.

Comment: Follow-up problem: if you just blindly `super` in `Base`, sometimes you end up calling `object.hello` with disastrous results!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just came across something like that! Sticking `super()` in base reaches `Right` and then throws `AttributeError` because, I guess, now the tree has been traversed and there's no more `super()` to follow. Where can I find some guidelines on using `super()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was hoping you could recommend some blog post, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @dotslash [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) is the classic, which you could have found by...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I knew about this article/talk, but thought that it wouldn't help a noob like me. :P :P I'll have a look at it. Thanks!